# How to display Transition for Bootstrap Modal Form in Vue?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I can't figure how to do a simple Fade-in / Fade-out transition when displaying a Bootstrap Modal form in Vue.  I can get the form to display properly but it just appears suddenly.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks so much in advance.  Wasted a good hour on this already :-~

```
<div id=app>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="showModal=true" >
  Launch demo modal
</button>


 <div v-if="showModal">
    <transition name="modal" >
      <div class="modal-mask">
        <div class="modal-wrapper">

        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true" @click="showModal = false">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control-plaintext" placeholder="Type text here...">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" @click="showModal = false">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="showModal = false">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </transition>
  </div>

</div> <!--Vue-->



new Vue({
  el: "#app",

  data: {
    message:'Vue is working',
        showModal:false

  },

  methods: {

  }
})
```

Please see Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/luckman8/vgeqd8of/173/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off you need to wrap element with `v-if` **into** `<transition></transition>`([Reference](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html)).
Then you have to define [CSS transitions](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#CSS-Transitions) in your CSS.

Also notice that `data` field should be a function that returns object, not an object.

> When defining a component, `data` must be declared as a function that
> returns the initial `data` object, because there will be many instances
> created using the same definition. If we use a plain object for data,
> that same object will be shared by reference across all instances
> created! By providing a `data` function, every time a new instance is
> created we can call it to return a fresh copy of the initial `data`.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      message: "Vue is working",
      showModal: false
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.modal-enter-active,
.modal-leave-active {
  transition: opacity .5s;
}

.modal-enter,
.modal-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id=app>
  <p>Vue + Bootstrap + Typescript + FontAwesome (and Console.js)</p>
  <p>Bootstrap message: {{message}}</p>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="showModal=true">
    Launch demo modal
  </button>
  <transition name="modal">
    <div v-if="showModal">
      <div class="modal-mask">
        <div class="modal-wrapper">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"  @click="showModal = false">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <input type="text" class="form-control-plaintext" placeholder="Type text here...">
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" @click="showModal = false">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="showModal = false">Save changes</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </transition>
</div>
```

Comment: add "appear "attribute to "transition" tag to complete the animation.
<transition name="modal" appear>